# Calculating Mediation Indirect Effects using GSEM in Stata or R for Count (Discrete) Mediators

Tags: generalized-linear-model, stata, structural-equation-modeling, negative-binomial-distribution, beta-regression

Estimating the following model in Stata helped me get the direct effects. This is a set of three models, a beta regression with the final outcome as the dependent variable, and two mediating negative binomial regressions. I've not been able to write the same model using `lavaan` or `mediation` packages in R, because lavaan assumes normality of residuals, and I could not figure out how to define more than one discrete mediator using the `mediation` package in R.

```
gsem (c.practice_days c.practice_count c.gpa c.gpa#c.practice_days c.gpa#c.practice_count -> final_0_1, family(beta) link(logit)) (1.counting_days 1.counting_days#c.gpa -> practice_days, nbreg) (1.counting_days 1.counting_days#c.gpa practice_days -> practice_count, nbreg), nocapslatent
```

However, I'm stuck with calculating the mediation indirect effects, because `gsem` does not support `estat teffects`.
I searched a lot, and finally came across this blog post, but I got frustrated after reading the second paragraph:

> Note that this is a case where all variables are continuous and all
> models are linear - we are only using `gsem` for its support of svy:,
> not its support of GLMs. Indirect effects are a more complicated
> topic in those models which we do not address here.

[The Stats documentation](https://www.stata.com/manuals/semexample42g.pdf) also explains only basic models with normality assumptions and uses `nlcom` to calculate the indirect effects.

Please advise on how to calculate the mediation indirect effects of this model.

Answer (score 0):

The following article may be helpful for you.

Direct and indirect effects in a logit model. The Stata Journal
Volume 10 Number 1: pp. 11-29

Maarten L. Buis
Department of Sociology
Tübingen University
Tübingen, Germany
maarten.buis@uni-tuebingen.de

https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0182